# Free Media Player for Android

Tags: gratis, android, music, media-player

I'm looking for a free Android media player that's more pleasant to use than [Songbird](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.songbirdnest.mediaplayer) (crashes/freezes on me) and the built-in Sony version (clumsy to navigate) that came preinstalled on my device (an [Xperia-S](http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_s-4369.php) smartphone).

I don't have many specific requirements, beyond:

- Supported formats should include MP3, OGG, and FLAC.
- If I browse to an album, tell it to play that album, and then hit 'next' on the last track in the album, the media player should go to the next album in my library and *not* back to the first track of current album.

That second point is the main reason I'm trying to find a different media player.  Being forced to manually switch from one album to the next is irritating to no end.

I'm after something that lets me select my starting point (whether that's a particular artist, album, or track) and then just traverses through my entire music library from that point until I tell it to stop.

**Update**

I tried installing [Poweramp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer), and it seems stable enough and provides the desired behavior when advancing to the next track.  So I guess the question is, is there a good free alternative to Poweramp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements seem to correspond to **[³](http://www.appbrain.com/app/org.abrantix.rockon.rockonnggl)** (pronounced: "Cube"), which I'm using on one of my devices. You might need to get used to its design first, though:

[image: Cubed]
<sup>Cubed (source: Google Play; click image to enlarge)</sup>

Turn the cube sidewards to switch between interpretes, and upside down to switch albums. Or switch to the "boring list view" if you prefer :)

- **Supported formats should include MPG, OGG, and FLAC:** I found no information on supported formats anywhere, and I don't use FLAC, so I cannot tell for sure. It played my MP§ fine, and if I remember correctly, I've also the one or other OGG in between
- **Continuous Play across albums:** Yes. Once the last title of one album is finished, it switches to the next album (not back to the first track of the current one) for me. I didn't play much with that, but the repeat-mode should be adjustable.

Only possible draw-back so far: the last update happened in February 2012, so it doesn't look like it's actively maintained anymore. Still, worth a look: If everything works fine, and you find all you need, that should be fine. Runs stable (though announced as "beta"), never crashed on me. For alternatives, be welcome to [browse my lists](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=193) :)

Comment: Thanks, this suits nicely.  Have you done any testing to see how the 3d visualization impacts upon battery life?  My phone seems noticeably hotter in that mode than when using "boring list view".

Comment: I rarely "spin the cube". Usually I just select my "starting point", and then let it play – controlling it via headset button, while the display is off. Never had my device going hot while playing music ;)